# I can take many physical forms, with your help

Tags: riddle

I am empty, yet I am tangible.
When I am full, I can be very wise.
No matter how full I am, I weigh about the same.
I can take many physical forms, with your help.

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previous answer(s):

> **A balloon.** A balloon is an empty container, until you fill it with air. No matter how much air you put in it, it still weighs the same. With the help of a skilled clown, a balloon can take the form of many different animals.
>
>  **A thought.** Thoughts are empty unless you fill them with meaning, at which point they are intelligent. A thought weighs the same - nothing at all? - regardless of how full it is. And of course, a thought can be bent and manipulated into many forms by the person who ... well, thought it. *Riddle was edited to include "tangible."*

New answer:

> Thanks to @Marmy1954's journal/diary idea, I figured the answer to be **a piece of paper**. The paper is empty until written on, can be very informative when full of words, weighs about the same when written on,  and the paper can be folded into different things, as in origami or paper airplanes, etc.

Comment: Good guess, but your guess is more known for "being full of hot air" than being wise.

Comment: I don't know that there is such a thing as an "empty thought".  Regardless, you helped inspire me to amend the riddle with the word "tangible".

Comment: Close enough.  The correct answer is a blank piece of paper.

Answer (score 1):

A notebook/journal/diary.  It is empty until written in.  Depending on the content, it can be wise.  It will still weigh about the same.  The form it takes depends on the author.

Guess this would hold true for any information medium.  Tape, CD, film.

Comment: Very close, but "I can take many forms", really means physical forms.  I will update riddle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> clay

I am empty, yet I am tangible.

> a blank slate or tabula rosa is empty, but still something physically tangible.  A lump of clay can be empty of meaning, but can still be touched.

When I am full, I can be very wise.

> tablets were written on in cuniform, and were used to pass on *important* wisdom.  Blank slates were made for writing on.  On the other hand, clay shaped into sculpture or art can also be full of meaning, and convey very wise ideas or impressions.

No matter how full I am, I weigh about the same.

> if your clay tablet is filled with letters or blank, it weighs the same because the amount of clay doesn't change - the letters aren't carved out, they're pressed in.  Or if the clay is used in art, again it can be full of meaning, but the meaning it is given is based on its shape, not weight, so the clay can be the same sized block as one empty of meaning.

I can take many physical forms, with your help.

> clay is very shape-able, it can be made into sculpture, building materials, fine dishware or rough bricks, jewelry, paint, even medicine.

Who or what am I?

> clay